# MATLAB plot's MarkerIndices property

Tags: matlab, plot, markers

How can I use `MarkerIndices` with `plot`?

```
x = linspace(-10,10,101);
y = sin(x);

plot(x, y,  'color', 'blue', ...
            'LineStyle','-', ...
            'Marker', 's', ...           
            'MarkerIndices', [1, 5, 10], ...        
            'MarkerEdgeColor', 'black',...
            'MarkerFaceColor','yellow');
```

**Error message**

```
Error using plot
There is no MarkerIndices property on the Line class.

Error in plotting3 (line 4)
plot(x, y,  'color', 'blue', ...
```

Comment: What's the version?

Comment: @Masoud, version 2015a.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**[*`MarkerIndices`*](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/create-line-plot-with-markers.html)** became available in *R2016b* version.

The workaround is plotting two times:

```
MarkerIndices = [1, 5, 10];
myplot = plot(x, y, 'b-.');
hold on;                 
mymarkers = plot(x(MarkerIndices), y(MarkerIndices), 'ro');    
legend(myplot)
```

This should work. I commented that this is in reference to a post on MathWorks Community. Will provide a link if found it.

P.S. This is the **[LINK](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/119402-how-to-set-a-marker-at-one-specific-point-on-a-plot-look-at-the-picture)** to the answer;