# Octave - Add a plot using markers in every nth data point, with or w/o lines

Tags: plot, octave, legend, variadic-functions

I have a script which creates quite a few figures, each with several plots.
The data points are very close together, so they cannot be distinguished.

A solution for me would be to use markers for every nth data point.

I could replace each (`plot`/`loglog`/etc.) sentence by two sentences,
one for plotting only lines (for which I mean to keep all data points), and
one for plotting only markers.
I should then set a single entry **to be added to** the legend, preferably using both the line and marker.
Ideally, I would have a quick way of replacing each instance of my "old plot" by the new version.

E.g.,...

... old sentences

```
pname = 'n';   % <-- This could actually be anything
%vvv Change only this vvv
plot(xdata, ydata, 'marker', '+', 'linestyle', '--', 'DisplayName', pname);
... many other plot commands, possibly inside for loops
%^^^ Change only this ^^^
hleg = legend();
set(hleg, "fontsize", 16, ...);
```

... new intended sentences

```
pname = 'n';   % <-- This could actually be anything
%vvv Changed only this vvv
%  plot(xdata, ydata, 'marker', '+', 'linestyle', '--', 'DisplayName', pname);
New 2 or 3 lines
% ... many other plot commands, possibly inside for loops
New 2 or 3 lines for each plot command
%^^^ Changed only this ^^^
hleg = legend();
set(hleg, "fontsize", 16, ...);
```

Note that the `plot` sentence I used in the example is highly schematic. I would like the solution to work in general.

**How can I accomplish this?**

Note:
Matlab added not so long ago `MarkerIndices` for this purpose.
See [MATLAB plot's MarkerIndices property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44076215/matlab-plots-markerindices-property), https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/create-line-plot-with-markers.html, and https://in.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/93864-can-i-put-markers-on-only-some-of-the-points-in-my-plot

---

I considered writing a function `plot_skip` that uses `varargin`.
This would perhaps be a quick way (although it would restrict the format of the parameter list, unless the function itself parses the argument list).
But then I need something like

```
function retval = plot_skip(varargin)
    nskip = varargin{1};
    symb = varargin{2};
    line = varargin{3};
    xdata = varargin{4};
    ydata = varargin{5};
    plot(xdata, ydata, line, varargin{6:end});
    plot(xdata(1:nskip:end), ydata(1:nskip:end), symb, varargin{6:end});     # <-- I need to use some flattened version of this list of arguments
    # COMMANDS NEEDED TO ADD A SINGLE ENTRY TO THE LEGEND
    retval = 0;
endfunction
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd add a third `plot` command only plotting the first value using the combined marker and line settings, and save that handle. Later, you can only feed that handle to the `legend` command, getting only a single entry:

```matlab
1;

function retval = plot_skip(varargin)
    nskip = varargin{1};
    symb = varargin{2};
    line = varargin{3};
    xdata = varargin{4};
    ydata = varargin{5};
    plot(xdata, ydata, line, varargin{6:end});
    hold on;
    plot(xdata(1:nskip:end), ydata(1:nskip:end), symb, varargin{6:end});
    h3 = plot(xdata(1), ydata(1), unique([line symb]));
    hold off;
    legend(h3);
    retval = 0;
endfunction


x = linspace(0, 4*pi, 101);
y1 = sin(x);
y2 = cos(x);

figure(1);
plot_skip(5, 'rx', 'r-', x, y1);

figure(2);
plot_skip(10, 'bo', 'b--', x, y2);
```

The two resulting figures look like this:

[image: Output 0]

[image: Output 1]

Currently, I only concatenate the marker and line settings and use `unique` to get rid of the double provided color information. If the colors of your markers and lines vary, you'd need to add some logic to handle that. Also, you might want to pass information for the `legend` entry via the `varargin`.

---

**EDIT:** I just realized, that in my second example, the second `-` get also removed by the `unique` command, thus the entry in the `legend` is wrong. So, the logic to combine the line and marker settings should be something more sophisticated...

---

**EDIT:** Since marker settings may include letters like `'x'`, and we need to remove the color information from one of the settings, I chose to use the color information from the marker settings, thus removing any letter from the line settings, and then combine both strings.

Also, I modified the code, such that plots can be added to existing figures. Then, you somehow need to store the handle from the function call:

```matlab
1;

function h = plot_skip(varargin)
    nskip = varargin{1};
    symb = varargin{2};
    line = varargin{3};
    xdata = varargin{4};
    ydata = varargin{5};
    hold on;
    plot(xdata, ydata, line, varargin{6:end});
    plot(xdata(1:nskip:end), ydata(1:nskip:end), symb, varargin{6:end});
    % Use color from marker setting, since line settings don't include letters
    comb = [symb, regexprep(line, '[a-zA-Z]', '')]
    h = plot(xdata(1), ydata(1), comb);
    hold off;
endfunction


x = linspace(0, 4*pi, 101);
y1 = sin(x);
y2 = cos(x);

figure(1);
legend_h = [];
legend_h(end+1) = plot_skip(5, 'rx', 'r-', x, y1);
legend_h(end+1) = plot_skip(10, 'bo', 'b--', x, y2);
legend(legend_h, {'sin(x)', 'cos(x)'});
```

This has the advantage, that you can provide any descriptions at the end of one figure.

The updated output:

[image: Updated output]

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer.
A first note is that I would need this to add plots to figures containing several of these, so I should be able to add the item in question to the legend, but not as a single item.

Comment: @sancho.sReinstateMonicaCellio I posted an edit. Maybe, that better fits your needs.

Comment: The idea of using three plots was very useful to put together [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65389711/2707864).

Answer (score 1):

You can specify which graphical objects to label legends for specifically. As per the documentation of `legend`:

> Legend labels are associated with the axes' children; The first label is assigned to the first object that was plotted in the axes, the second label to the next object plotted, etc.  To label specific data objects, without labeling all objects, provide their graphic handles in the input HOBJS.

Here's an example.

```matlab
t   = 0 : 0.01 : 2 * pi;
x   = 1 : 50 : length( t );

hs  = plot( t   , sin( t    ), '-' ); hold on    % sine   (line)
hsm = plot( t(x), sin( t(x) ), 'o' );            % sine   (markers)
hc  = plot( t   , cos( t    ), '-' );            % cosine (line)
hcm = plot( t(x), cos( t(x) ), 'o' ); hold off   % cosine (markers)

legend( [hsm, hc], {'Sin Markers', 'Cos Line'} );
```

[image]

Disclaimer: I'm using octave 6.1.0. I don't know if this functionality is new.

---

PS. If you want both the line and the marker to appear, making two separate calls with the markers first and the lines second, seems to result in the markers overlapping the lines. E.g.

```matlab
legend off   % refreshing just in case
legend( [hsm, hcm], {'Whatever man'  , 'Who cares'       } );
legend( [hs , hc ], {'Combined sines', 'Combined cosines'} );
```

[image]

Disclaimer 2: I have no idea if this is a bug or a feature :p

**UPDATE**

It seems like the requirements have changed and `legend()` specifically needs to be called without arguments, and a plot's visibility to legend needs to be controlled from within a very specific scope.

In this case you can use the `handlevisibility` propery of the plot object.

```matlab
handlevisibility: "callback" | "off" | {"on"}

    If handlevisibility is "off", the object's handle
    is not visible in its parent’s "children" property.
```

Example:

```matlab
t   = 0 : 0.01 : 2 * pi;
x   = 1 : 50 : length( t );
h1 = plot( t, sin(t), 'b-' ); hold on;
h2 = plot( t(x), sin(t(x)), 'ro' );
h3 = plot( t(x), sin(t(x)), 'g-o' ); hold off
set( h3, 'visible', 'off' )
set( [h1, h2], 'handlevisibility', 'off' )
legend()
```

Comment: Please see [added answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65389711/2707864)... I would be glad to hear your comments.

Comment: @sancho.sReinstateMonicaCellio hm. Your question has changed significantly. It's now effectively a new question. However, even with the new question, I think you're overthinking this. You can have the same effect simply by turning a plot's `handlevisibility` "off". This will prevent it from being picked up in the legend. Honestly though, why would you not use intended functionality and just call legend with the handles of interest? Are you not in control of the part of the code that calls the `legend` command?

Comment: @sancho.sReinstateMonicaCellio I have updated my answer with an example.

Comment: @sancho.sReinstateMonicaCellio ah sorry, I read the updated question before your answer. I see you've discovered this yourself. Well done!

Comment: Thanks! 
PS: The intention of the question did not change, it was always to keep as much of the old code as possible, and changing only the "`plot`" sentences looked like the best option. 
I simply added an example to illustrate what was meant by "Ideally, I would have a quick way of replacing each instance of my "old plot" by the new version." 
Not touching the rest of the code, if possible, was implied (be it using `legend` with or without parameters).

Comment: @sancho.sReinstateMonicaCellio I'm glad you resolved your issue successfully. :) On a personal note, I like your octave questions on SO, they tend to scratch the right kind of itch. My only slight criticism would be that often (as is the case here), their framing (and similarly with self-answers) feels a bit too detailed and specific to a particular codebase/context (sometimes evolving as the question gains traction), rather than framed in a focused way that would be useful to future visitors with a similar problem ( which is SO's purpose) or easily reproducible by answerers. There is [...]

Comment: [...] still good information in there, but one would have to sift through the implementation particulars to figure out if it's relevant. Eg. the custom function in your answer, while good software engineering top-down design in principle, obfuscates the main issue, and makes it hard for a casual user to just 'copy-paste-and-see' (not to mention introduces a bunch of secondary questions, which are probably more 'code review' than 'stack overflow' related). I think making your question more focused and MCVE-based would add further value to your questions (and answers)! :)

Comment: Thanks, will take note and think about it. I tend to think SO-centered (perhaps not very successfully, though).

Answer (score 1):

I wrote function `plot_skip` below.
The key was setting property `'HandleVisibility'` to `'off'` when needed.
This function is ready for copy-pasting.
Then in the code body, one has to only replace

```
plot(xdata, ydata, ...)
```

with

```
plot_skip(nskip, xdata, ydata, 'marker', marker, 'linestyle', linestyle, ...)
```

in that order.
It can even be used as

```
plot_skip(nskip, xdata, ydata, 'marker', marker, 'linestyle', 'none', ...)
```

if need be (e.g., within a loop or another function).

Pros:

1. **It seems to do the job**. I tested it under various scenarios, and all worked.
2. It only requires changing each sentence `plot(...)` to `plot_skip(nskip,...)`, nothing else!
3. It can be copy-pasted into another function `loglog_skip` (as I did).
4. It becomes accessible system-wide.

Cons:

1. It requires a certain order in the arguments.
   To avoid this, one should write a parser inside the function. Perhaps some or all of the code of Octave itself could be taken advantage of.

Code:

```
%========================================================
% PLOT USING EVERY OTHER nth SYMBOL
% Parameters:
%  varargin: cell array containing all input arguments.
%  Expected format:
%  varargin{1}: nskip
%  varargin{2}: xdata
%  varargin{3}: ydata
%  varargin{4}: 'marker'
%  varargin{5}: marker
%  varargin{6}: 'linestyle'
%  varargin{7}: linestyle
%  varargin{8:end}: all the rest
% =============================================================================

function retval = plot_skip(varargin)
    nskip = varargin{1};
    xdata = varargin{2};
    ydata = varargin{3};
    if (strcmp(varargin{4}, 'marker') != 1)
        warning("Graphics:plotskip-nonstadard-varargin",
          "plot_skip: \'marker\' argument expected");
        retval = 1;
        return;
    endif
    marker = varargin{5};
    if (strcmp(varargin{6}, 'linestyle') != 1)
        warning("Graphics:plotskip-nonstadard-varargin",
          "plot_skip: \'linestyle\' argument expected");
        retval = 1;
        return;
    endif
    linestyle = varargin{7};

    plot(xdata(1:nskip:end), ydata(1:nskip:end), 'marker', marker, 'linestyle', 'none', varargin{8:end}, 'HandleVisibility', 'off');
    plot(xdata(1:end), ydata(1:end), 'marker', 'none', 'linestyle', linestyle, varargin{8:end}, 'HandleVisibility', 'off');
    plot(xdata(1), ydata(1), 'marker', marker, 'linestyle', linestyle, varargin{8:end});
    
    retval = 0;

endfunction

% =============================================================================
```

Note:
This brings one unrelated question, which I would post separately later on...

1. Is it ok to issue several `warning`s, with a given `id`, but varying the `template`?

   This is what I do in my code.

Answer (score 0):

This method from Matlab described here works for octave:
https://es.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/155938-placing-markers-at-every-tenth-data-point-and-creating-label
(I copy the content here)

The trick is to generate three plots.

1. The first with the line,
2. the second with the markers,
3. and the third an empty plot with both line and marked,

and use this third line for the legend

```
 x = 0:pi/100:2*pi;
 y = sin(x);
 h = plot(x, y, '-b', x(1:10:end), y(1:10:end), 'bd', NaN, NaN, '-bd');
 legend(h(3), 'my label');
```

[image]